# How to export array in csv or txt in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I'm trying to export array to txt or csv file. I've been trying with numpy but i always get some error like 
`TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U14') and format specifier ('%.18e')`

Here is my code without numpy that works great but I need help with part how to export it.

```
peoples = []
for content in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('x234'):
    people = content.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="zstrim"]').text
    if people != "Django" and people != "Rooky" :
        pass
        peoples.append([people, 1, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")])
print(peoples)
```

Really need some help with this.

Comment: why you trying to use numpy (linear algebra library) instead of [python standart library for reading and writing csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Comment: @Arnial  how? do you have code suggestion how to do that on your way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are doing something like:

```
In [1339]: peoples=[]

In [1340]: for _ in range(3):
   ......:     peoples.append([234, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")])
   ......:     

In [1341]: peoples
Out[1341]: [[234, '22/06/16 14:57'], [234, '22/06/16 14:57'], [234, '22/06/16 14:57']]
```

`peoples` is an array (or here a list of lists), that contains, among other things formatted dates.

```
In [1342]: np.savetxt('test.txt',peoples)
...    
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U14') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e')
```

Since I didn't specify `fmt` it constructed a default one, consisting of two `%.18e` fields.  That's great for general formatting of numbers.  But the data includes 14 characters strings ('U14' - unicode in Python3).

If I tell it to use `%s`, the generic string format, I get:

```
In [1346]: np.savetxt('test.txt',peoples, fmt='%s', delimiter=',')

In [1347]: cat test.txt
234,22/06/16 14:57
234,22/06/16 14:57
234,22/06/16 14:57
```

Not ideal, but still it works.  `fmt='%20s'` would be better.

I glossed over a another nuance.  `peoples` is a list of lists.  `np.savetxt` works with arrays, so it first turns that into an array with:

```
In [1360]: np.array(peoples)
Out[1360]: 
array([['234', '22/06/16 14:57'],
       ['234', '22/06/16 14:57'],
       ['234', '22/06/16 14:57']], 
      dtype='<U14')
```

But this turns both columns into `U14` strings.  So I have to format both columns with `%s`.  I can't use a numeric format on the first.  What I need to do first is make a structured array with a numeric field(s) and a string field.  I know how to do that, but I won't get into the details now.

As per comments, it could be simpler to format each `peoples` line as a complete string, and write that to a file.

```
In [1378]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    for _ in range(3):
        f.write('%10d,%20s\n'%(234, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")))
   ......:         

In [1379]: cat test.txt
       234,      22/06/16 15:18
       234,      22/06/16 15:18
       234,      22/06/16 15:18
```

Comment: Ok this helps a lot, because now I understand where is the problem. I used your last part of code, surf more a bit and find solution thanks to you. So here is the final result that will append all every time it runs  I added this after `pass` .... `mybook = open('archive.csv', 'a')
                    mybook.write('%20s,%20s\n'%(people, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")))
                    mybook.close()`

Answer (score 1):

[hpauj's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979006/2141635) answer explains you why your code error but using the *csv* lib and writing as you go is probably a lot easier:

```
import csv

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for content in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('x234'):
        people = content.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="zstrim"]').text
        if people != "Django" and people != "Rooky":
            wr.writerow([people, 1, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")])
```

Comment: yeah csv is much simpler. Thanks for this code it helped a lot! But I must admit hpauj's answer helped me to understand how it works.